# Count multiple key values in xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

I want to take unique count of code for each Can, Tin (this name might vary..)

So the output should be:
Can - 3
Tin - 2

```
<root>
  <Item>
     <Pack>
       <Type>Can</Type>
       <Code>1234</Code>
     </Pack>

      <Pack>
        <Type>Tin</Type>
       <Code>3456</Code>
      </Pack>  
  </Item>

<Item>
  <Pack>
       <Type>Can</Type>
       <Code>1234</Code>
     </Pack>

      <Pack>
        <Type>Can</Type>
       <Code>7890</Code>
      </Pack>
</Item>

<Item>
  <Pack>
       <Type>Tin</Type>
       <Code>3478</Code>
     </Pack>

      <Pack>
        <Type>Can</Type>
       <Code>7890</Code>
      </Pack>
</Item>
</root>
```

I have concatenated 2 nodes using key

```
<xsl:key name="K1" match="Pack" use="concat(Type, '|', Code)" /> 

<xsl:for-each select="root/Item/Pack[count(. | key('K1', concat(Type,'|', Code) )[1]) = 1]">
 <xsl:value-of select="Type"/>
 <xsl:value-of select="count(key('K1', concat(Type,'|', Code)))"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Currently I am getting:
Can2
Can1
Can1
Tin1
Tin1

Comment: For Can I see only 2 unique values: 1234 and 7890.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you actually want to count the number of `Item`s in each `Type` (where an `Item` can be in more than one `Type`), try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:key name="pack-by-type" match="Pack" use="Type" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <!-- for each distinct Type -->
    <xsl:for-each select="Item/Pack[count(. | key('pack-by-type', Type)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:value-of select="Type"/>
        <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
        <!-- count the number of Items with this Type -->
        <xsl:value-of select="count(key('pack-by-type', Type)/..)"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
Can - 3
Tin - 2
```

---

If you really want to count the number of unique `Code`s in each `Type`, you would need to do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:key name="k1" match="Pack" use="Type" />
<xsl:key name="k2" match="Pack" use="concat(Type, '|', Code)" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <!-- for each distinct Type -->
    <xsl:for-each select="Item/Pack[count(. | key('k1', Type)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:value-of select="Type"/>
        <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
        <!-- count the number of distinct codes with this Type -->
        <xsl:value-of select="count(key('k1', Type)[count(. | key('k2', concat(Type, '|', Code))[1]) = 1])"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but then the result will be:

```
Can - 2
Tin - 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it helped me to solve many similar projects